# how to get all value in dropdownlist in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a dropdown where user select some values and moves to other dropdownlist in sorted order by javascript. How can I get the chosen value in second dropdownlist in next page to a PHP variable ?

```
<form name="Example" action="next.php" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="Features" size="9" MULTIPLE>
                <option value="2">Row 2</option>
                <option value="4">Row 4</option>
                <option value="5">Row 5</option>
                <option value="6">Row 6</option>
                <option value="7">Row 7</option>
                <option value="8">Row 8</option>
                <option value="9">Row 9</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <input type="Button" value=">>" style="width:100px" onClick="SelectMoveRows(document.Example.Features,document.Example.FeatureCodes)">
            <br>
            <input type="Button" value="<<" style="width:100px" onClick="SelectMoveRows(document.Example.FeatureCodes,document.Example.Features)"><br>

            <input type="Button" value=">>>>" style="width:100px" onClick="selectAll(document.Example.Features);SelectMoveRows(document.Example.Features,document.Example.FeatureCodes)"><br>

            <input type="Button" value="<<<<" style="width:100px" onClick="selectAll(document.Example.FeatureCodes);SelectMoveRows(document.Example.FeatureCodes,document.Example.Features)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="FeatureCodes[]" id="FeatureCodes" size="9" MULTIPLE>
                <option value="1">Row 1</option>
                <option value="3">Row 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The value of the selected element in your second form field should be in:

```
$_POST['FeatureCodes'][0];
```

If you only have one `FeatureCodes` form on the page then you can remove the `[]` from your HTML and access it using `$_POST['FeatureCodes'];`

Comment: Thanks to replay Paulpro!!! I had already tried this ($_POST['FeatureCodes'];) and got an error Undefined index: FeatureCodes, but when select all values in Second  dropdownlist i.e. FeatureCodes i get all values in next page. Is there is any way to get all values in FeatureCodes without user selection or  all values should select in FeatureCodes on submit.